# Remove trailing slash - Not just using htaccess

Tags: magento-1.8, url, seo

I have noted that Magento adds trailing slashes to most urls.

1. https://www.example.com/checkout/cart/
2. https://www.example.com/customer/account/create/

In my htaccess I have it to strip off the trailing slash and 301 redirect but I was wondering where in Magento I would need to edit to stop the trailing slash happening in the first place.

I have found http://developersushant.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/remove-trailing-slash-from-magento-urls.html but this means moving Abstract.php to the local folder which I ideally dont wish to do